# need to focus the particular input while click the button

Tags: angular

I create an 9 input with corresponding 9 buttons in ngFor I need to focus the input when click the corresponding button.I attached the code for your reference

I already acheive this through document.getElement But I need to acheive this in angular way.

```
<div (window:resize)="myfunction($event)" >
  <div class="row"  *ngFor="let her of heroes;let i=index">
    <div class="col-sm-3">{{her.name}}</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <input  id={{i}} #ref class="grid inborder" #validation1 type="text" (keydown)="chng($event.target.value)" >
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <button class="editCLs" (click)="edit1(i)">{{her.edit}}</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I acheived this through below code

```
edit1(ej) {

    document.getElementById(ej).focus();
    //this.ref.nativeElement.getElementById(ej).focus();
  }
```

But I need to acheive through angular way.

I need to focus the corresponding input while click the button.[Please refer this link](https://firstapp5.firebaseapp.com/)

Please share If spark any idea. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55748075/1009922).

Comment: Thank you @ConnorsFan. This link is very helpful to me.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this.

```
 @ViewChildren("input") inputs: QueryList<any>

edit1(ej) {
    this.inputs[i].nativeElement.focus();
  }
```